# How do I filter parents properties of ManyToMany Object?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I am new to Django and had a problem today

I have two models, `Program` and `Member`.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Sum

class Program(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    fee = models.IntegerField(default=10)  # Arbitrary Property

class Member(models.Model):
    programs = models.ManyToManyField(Program, related_name='members')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    
    # I tried this but it gives me all of the sum of all the programs' fees :
    # fees_for_member = models.IntegerField(default=Program.objects.prefetch_related('members').aggregate(Sum('fee'))['fee__sum'])

    # This results in an error:
    # fees_for_member = programs.aggregate(Sum('fee'))['fee__sum']
```

Each program has a `fee`, and `Member` has an IntegerField called `fees_for_member` or just `fees` whose default value is the sum of all the `Program fees` the `Member` has signed up for.

My question is, how do I filter *just* the `Programs` which the `member` is in?

I have tried `Program.objects.prefetch_related('members').aggregate(Sum('fee'))['fee__sum'])` but it returns the sum of *all* the Programs' Fees.

I also tried `programs.aggregate(Sum('fee'))['fee_sum']` 
but it gives me this error :
`AttributeError: 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute 'aggregate'`

What can I do for this? I know I am missing something, but I'm not sure what it is. I spent hours searching through Django docs and SO, but I just can't find the answer so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a property for fees_for_member instead of a field as this has to be calculated dynamically:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    programs = models.ManyToManyField(Program, related_name='members')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    @property
    def fees_for_member(self):
        return self.programs.aggregate(models.Sum('fee'))['fee__sum']
```

This should work.

**Solution 2:**

If Program.fee is a property as well, and properties are python code (not values in database) you can not use database level operations. An equivalent solution is:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    programs = models.ManyToManyField(Program, related_name='members')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    @property
    def fees_for_member(self):
        return sum([p.fee for p in self.programs.all()])
```

Some docs about this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#model-methods